# why am i getting a 400 (bad request) error when using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dropdown which calls a js function:

```
                <select class="form-control" name="product" id="product" onchange="populateProductLine(this.value)">
                    <option selected="selected" value="" disabled="">Select Product</option>
                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                        <option value="<?=$product['productId']?>"><?=$product['productName']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
```

the js function then uses ajax to call a controller method:

```
function populateProductLine(productId) {

if (productId == '') {
//document.getElementById("chargeable").value = "";
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(myObj);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/getproduct(" + productId + ")",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

the controller method (just dummy data for now):

```
    public function getproduct($product_id) {

    $myArr = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");

    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

    echo $myJSON;

}
```

Why do I get a 400 (bad request) error? I use Codeigniter.

Comment: I would recommend you to use ajax for request that is more simple and easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter, submitting `()` URI characters are not allowed and will result a `400 (Bad Request)` http status.

Fix the URI on your ajax request like below :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/getproduct/" + productId,true);
```

Comment: Thanks hasta. I'm kicking myself over not seeing something so obvious, im not sure why i tried to pass a parameter in brackets in a url haha.

Answer (score 0):

js function then uses ajax to call a controller method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateProductLine(productId) {
if (productId == '') 
{
  alert('if');
}
else 
{
$.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost/narson/stackoverflow/getproduct",
     type:"post",
     data:{'productId':productId},
     datatype: "json",
     success:function(data,status)
     {
        console.log(data);
     }
     });
    }
  }
</script>


 public function getproduct() {

    $productId = $this->input->post('productId');
    $myArr = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");

    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

    echo $myJSON;

}
```